# Let $P=\left\{ \left( x,y,z\right) :2x+y-5z=0\right\}$. Find the basis of $P$. Find the distance between the vector $(1,3,2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

- Let $P=\left\{ \left( x,y,z\right) :2x+y-5z=0\right\}$. Find the basis of $P$. Find the distance between $P$ and the vector $(1,3,2)$.

My solution for the basis: Take $(5,0,2), (1,-2,0)$ in $P$. Then, since these vector are linearly independent, these are a basis for $P$.

**Can you help for distance?**

Comment: the distance between the vector and...?

Comment: @Dan and $P$. Edited.

Comment: Find **a** basis of $P$. There isn't a unique basis!

Comment: i would convert the equation of the plane into the Hessian Normalform $$\frac{2x+y-5z}{\pm\sqrt{4+1+25}}=0$$

Comment: is this right a distance betwwen a plane and a vector?

Comment: @user296113 Then, $(5,0,2)$ is a basis for $P$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $P$ is a line, isn't it?

Comment: @Kahler No, $P$ is a plane.

Comment: $P$ is a plane.

Comment: $P$ describes a plane in 3D

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance of the vector $(1,3,2)$ and the plane $P$ is given by the length of the component of $(1,3,2)$ orthogonal to $P$. Given a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in\mathbf{R}^3$ and a plane with equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$, the length of the orthogonal component of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with respect to the plane is given by 
$$ \frac{\lvert ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$
In this case, then, the answer is 
$$ \frac{\lvert 2(1)+1(3)-5(2)\rvert}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2+(-5)^2}}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{30}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Find a vector perpendicular to the plane. (How?)
2. Displace your point of interest along that vector to a point in the plane.

More hints:

> Take the cross product of the two vectors in your bases to find a perpendicular vector.